# Wcf duplex connection with https reply endpoint

Tags: .net, wcf, ssl, asynchronous, duplex

I have a duplex Wcf connection with callback, which works ok via http, (when i use 
`<compositeDuplex  clientBaseAddress="http://localhost:8678/.."/>`), but when i try to switch that adress to https (`"https://localhost:8678/.."`), i get that error
from the server side when it's trying to reply

> This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not
>   configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case

Can i somehow programatically install certificate for that temp reply endpoint?
Maybe somehow create ServiceHost object  and use it when i create my InstanceContext?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we use https protocol address to communicate with each other, we need to set up the certificate with following command.

> netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8000
>   certhash=0000000000003ed9cd0c315bbb6dc1c08da5e6
>   appid={00112233-4455-6677-8899-AABBCCDDEEFF}

Here are the official details.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-configure-a-port-with-an-ssl-certificate
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/http/add-sslcert
If you host the service with internet information server (IIS), you could complete this with IIS.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-configure-an-iis-hosted-wcf-service-with-ssl
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: I don't think that is the answer for my concrete case, cause when you use composite duplex in wcf with call back, duplrxllex client creates temp endpoint for reply call back, and i can't find the way to configure that 'temp'  endpoint. And i need to make it by the 'code' or 'configuration xml' way

Comment: When any channel(IP:Portnumber) is used to create Https communication. the specific port needs a certificate to encrypt the data. You could try to use the above command. On the client end, open the CMD shell with administrator privilege, input the corresponding command.